# How to avoid discarding the '\' character by PHP's bin2hex?

Tags: php

```
$text = '\\u'
$s = bin2hex($text);
echo hex2bin($str);
```

It will output \u, but I need \\u. The '$text' could be a normal string, so I can't do something like

```
'\' . $text'
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `\\\\u` It's not `bin2hex` that "discards" it, check `echo $text;`

Comment: @zerkms, yes, you're right. Maybe I should try 'addslashes'.